# Opening a Socket.IO connection in a google chrome extension

Tags: javascript, sockets, google-chrome-extension, websocket

I'm trying to figure out how to open a connection to an external Socket.IO server every time the user visits a new page from a google chrome extension. This is my first extension, so it's a bit tough.

I tried using an iframe and the history.onVisit event, but no luck so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research I realized that Socket.IO doesn't currently support cross-site connections. So that idea's out.

Comment: This is not correct, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8970880/cross-domain-socket-io and http://socket.io/#faq for why, but to paraphrase: " Native WebSockets are cross-domain by design, socket.io serves a flash policy file for cross-domain flash communication, XHR2 can use CORS, and finally you can always use JSONP"

Answer (score 0):

[socket.io](http://socket.io) does support cross-site connections using `jsonp polling` now or is that a new feature?