# How can i prevent cross-domain connections and allow access from my domain only?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I am new to Node.JS , and this question might be a bit trivial .
I am using something like this on the client side :-

```
 var sock = io.connect('http://www.mydomain.com:3000');
          sock.on('connect', function () {
                console.log("Connected successfully");
                sock.emit("_rK",{});
          });
```

My question is : How do i prevent cross domain connections ? Or simply , how do i prevent users from connecting to the web socket without using the website ?

According to this : [Cross-domain connection in Socket.IO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8970880/cross-domain-socket-io) , cross domain connections are allowed in socket.io .

Answer (score 2):

You may find `origins` option useful ([wiki page](https://github.com/LearnBoost/Socket.IO/wiki/Configuring-Socket.IO)):

server.js:

```
io.set('origins', 'www.mydomain.com:3000');
```

You can find more information about `origins` format [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21711242/2600208).

Comment: Is it secure ? Or can it be spoofed ?

Comment: It relies on `origin` (or `referer`) request header, so in browser it's ok. But the attacker may send fake header via `curl` or something. If you want to prevent this kind of attacks, you need to implement authentication system with [CSRF](http://owasp.com/index.php/CSRF) protection

Comment: @Oleg I am doing it like this, is it okay? io.origins((origin, callback) => {
    if (origin.indexOf('myserver.com') === -1) {
        console.log('denied request to socket io from this origin ' + origin);
        return callback('origin not allowed', false);
    }
    //  console.log("allowed access to socket io from this origin " + origin);
    callback(null, true);
});
sOME other website is still able to connect to my chat site users. how do i stop that?

Answer (score 0):

You could check for the `originating url` at the time of socket connection on the server. But that is not much safe and can easily be spoofed.

A technique that I use to verify web sockets is to send a token to the client and append it to the url of the socket server like this

`ws://mysocket.server/token` or `ws://mysocket.server?token="somerandomtoken"`

and then verify this token at the time of socket connection once. If the token can not be verified the server simply refuses the socket connection.

Comment: On what basis do you check the token ? You must've stored them against  the user's ip/user-agent . If so they can be spoofed too , right ? So basically i just need the tokenized url to connect to the socket server .

Comment: yes I think random tokens are best way to do this. You only need this once while authenticating the socket.

Comment: But you would send the token to the client, how do you know it's the authorised client?

Answer (score 0):

Easy and security!

In the main file place it before io.on('connection'), add the lines:

```
io.set('origins', 'yoursite.com:*');

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
```

Comment: I am doing it like this, is it okay? io.origins((origin, callback) => {
    if (origin.indexOf('myserver.com') === -1) {
        console.log('denied request to socket io from this origin ' + origin);
        return callback('origin not allowed', false);
    }
    //  console.log("allowed access to socket io from this origin " + origin);
    callback(null, true);
});