# Using Socket.IO server and client on different subdomains

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

I have two subdomains:

- socket.mydomain.com - The Socket.IO server
- app.mydomain.com - A web app that I'd like to connect to my web socket.

In the landing page for app.mydomain.com, I've linked in the Socket.IO client script, and successfully created an IO object, like so:

```
<script src=https://socket.mydomain.com/socket.io/socket.io.js></script>

<script type=text/javascript>
  const socket = io();
  socket.on('message', data => console.log(data));
</script>
```

However, rather than trying to connect to `socket.mydomain.com`, the client is trying to connect to `app.mydomain.com`. Because there's no socket at `app.mydomain.com`, it fails and keeps retrying.

Is there a way to connect my app at `app.mydomain.com` to my socket at `socket.mydomain.com`? Or is this impossible?

**Update**

Most all of the existing answers relating to this question now use outdated code, because Socket.IO has recently upgraded to 1.0 (1.4 in fact). However, even taking these code changes into account, it *seems* like Socket.IO doesn't allow what I'm trying to do.

When Socket.IO makes the initial connection to the server, it sends an XHR with the `withCredentials` settings set to true. But you can't have `withCredentials` set to true *and* allow CORS on the server. So it seems my question is actually, 'Is there a way around this problem?'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cross Domain Socket.Io](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8970880/cross-domain-socket-io)

Comment: Try to set the origins on the server-side: `io.set('origins', 'domain or IP here');` where `io` is your own defined variable.

Comment: Thanks @Gothdo - checking that out now. Will post here or delete my question if that works.

Comment: On the client side, I tried `var socket = io.connect('socket.mydomain.com')`, and now I receive the following error: A wildcard '*' cannot be used in the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header when the credentials flag is true. Origin 'http://app.mydomain.com' is therefore not allowed access. The credentials mode of an XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.

Comment: @Gothdo just posted an update.

Comment: @C0dekid.php thanks for that suggestion, but part of the problem is that I need to allow all origins.

Comment: Have you checked [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33912510/3853934) answer? It's for Socket.IO 1.3.7.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To accomplish what I wanted, several things needed to be configured correctly, and I needed to use the latest Socket.IO syntax:

- CORS must be enabled on the `socket.mydomain.com` server (`Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header set to `*`)
- Acceptable transports had to be specified on the server (`socket.mydomain.com`):

  ```
  const app = express();
  const server = http.createServer(app);
  const io = require('socket.io')(server, {
    transports: ['websocket', 'xhr-polling']
  });
  ```
- The remote server and acceptable transports had to be specified on the client (`app.mydomain.com`):

  ```
  const socket = io('socket.mydomain.com', {
    transports: ['websocket', 'xhr-polling']
  });
  ```

Comment: I don't want to use xhr-polling in tranpsorts as it is using xhr in browser network and delaying other api requests which is delaying response. And my backend server (api) domain is api.domain.com so should i use socket.api.domain.com in client??