# Socket IO - Chrome Extension CORS

Tags: google-chrome-extension, socket.io

I am working on a chrome extension that uses socket IO to communicate with a backend server. The problem is that my connection seems to be blocked by cross origin policies.

My server is running on localhost, bit the chrome extension that i am loading from local directory has some other "origin" header and thus my requests are blocked.

How can I allow a socket IO connection from local chrome extension ?

The request:

```
https://localhost:8000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LkNvOuH net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED
```

The headers:

```
Provisional headers are shown
Accept:*/*
Origin:chrome-extension://acgnndapfmilgphkhkdkipfiipikkjki
Referer:https://docs.google.com/presentation
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.59 Safari/537.36
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check this [documentation](https://socket.io/get-started/chat/) which shows how you can properly integrate Socket.IO.

As detailed, Socket.IO is composed of two parts:

- A server that integrates with (or mounts on) the Node.JS HTTP Server: `socket.io`
- A client library that loads on the browser side: `socket.io-client`

Note also that during development, `socket.io` serves the client automatically, so you only have to install one module:

```
npm install --save socket.io
```

That will install the module and add the dependency to `package.json`. Edit `index.js` to add it:

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  console.log('a user connected');
});

http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

Furthermore,

> Notice that I’m not specifying any URL when I call io(), since it defaults to trying to connect to the host that serves the page.

Lastly, you may want to also check the suggested solutions from this [thread](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client/issues/641) or from this related [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33912510).

Answer (score 0):

In Case you use Express framework on backend, I solved it by adding [cors](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors) middleware to the server  and i added this line `app.use(cors())`