# Disable CORS in Mozilla Firefox for development purpose: Local Websocket connection in Tampermonkey

Tags: javascript, firefox, socket.io, cors, tampermonkey

I have a Tampermonkey addon contacting my local dev server using Websockets. This doesn't work and throw the following error:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://127.0.0.1:3000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=N9Bvvb3. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).
```

So I tried the first three Addons found by a search by *CORS*:

- https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/cors-unblock/?src=search
- https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/cross-domain-cors/?src=search
- https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/cors-everywhere/?src=search

None of them seems to work. How can I fix this?

I know the security minds behind CORS. Since my software targets developers and is only be used locally, I don't need it. So I'm searching for an *easy* solution to allow my tampermonkey script to connect to localhost when accessing a web page like https://example.com.

I also tried different things on the server side to make CORS properly work like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33912510/9428314) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32701564/9428314), but still getting the error.

#### Server

```
let app = express();
app.use(express.static(path.resolve(`${__dirname}/../dist`)));
const certDir = "certs";
let httpOpts = {
  key: fs.readFileSync(`${certDir}/localhost.key`),
  cert: fs.readFileSync(`${certDir}/localhost.crt`),
  requestCert: false,
  rejectUnauthorized: false
};
var http = require("https").createServer(httpOpts, app);
var io = require("socket.io")(http);
```

#### Tampermonkey client scirpt

```
const localDevUrl = "https://127.0.0.1:3000";
this.socket = io(localDevUrl, { secure: true });
```

Comment: Why was my question downvoted?! Sad to see, that not at least a reason is provided as comment...

Comment: I have the same issue on firefox. Have you ever figured out?