# io.to(socket.id).emit() not working on cross domain

Tags: node.js, sockets, websocket, socket.io

how to emit the event with using particular_room `[io.to(socket.id).emit('sendData') ]`at cross domain

I've tried this,

```
server side
io.emit('sendData', data);

clientside
var socket = io('https://localhost:3000/', { transports: ['websocket'] });

socket.on('sendData', function (data) {
    console.log(data);

})
```

above syntax are perfectly working on cross domain

but I want to emit with particular room at cross domain

```
  io.to(socket.id).emit('sendData', data)
io.broadcast.to(socketid).emit('message', 'for your eyes only'); //sending to individual socketid
```

Reference link -> [Cross-domain connection in Socket.IO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8970880/)

Kindly help to solve this!

Answer (score 1):

I Understood your code, you just emit the initial connection on the socket.io server

```
     io.on("connection", function(socket){
        socket.emit('sendsocketid', data);
        
        })
        
        
        Cross-domain clientside
        var socket = io('https://localhost:3000/', { transports: ['websocket'] });
        
        var obj= [];
        socket.on('sendsocketid', function (data) {
            console.log(data);
    // Now You Can Customize the or add the client Socket .id
          var NewSocketid = {
             id: socket.id
}
Obj.push(data, NewSocketid)

socket.emit("emitnewSocketId", Obj)
    })
socket.on("emitnewSocketId", function(data){
consoleo.log(Obj[1].NewSocketid)

//Now You can emit the new socket id
    io.to(Obj[1].NewSocketid).emit('sendData', data) 
   
})
```