# Listen for socket.io connection inside chrome extension

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, google-chrome-extension, socket.io

I'm able to send socket.io connections **from** my extension **to** my server, but I cannot hear emits from my server inside my extension. I've found conflicting answers regarding this question:

[Opening a Socket.IO connection in a google chrome extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3509756/opening-a-socket-io-connection-in-a-google-chrome-extension) says this can't be done; and

[Cross-domain connection in Socket.IO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8970880/cross-domain-socket-io) says it can.

Is there any special configuration I must change in order to accept emits from my socket server?

**EDIT**:

(Note: I'm using AngularJS, but it shouldn't be relevant to this question)

socketFactory.js:

```
myApp.factory('socketFactory', function($rootScope) {
  var socket = io.connect('//dev.mydomain.com', {'path': '/api/socket'});
  return socket;
}
```

inject.js:

```
var packetData = { 'some':'data', 'roomId':'123abc' };
socketFactory.emit('room:join', packetData);
...
socketFactory.on('room:update', function (data) {
  console.log('Received data from socket server');
  console.log(data)
}
```

socket.js (server-side):

```
socket.on('room:join', function ( data ) {
  // Setting socketId to detect disconnect
  data.user.socketId = socket.id;

  socket.join( data.roomId, function() {
    // Some code ...
    io.sockets.to(data.roomId).emit('room:update', {'some':'data', 'roomId': '123abc'});
  }
});
```

That's the basic setup of my connection. This system works perfectly when I launch the app in non-extension mode (we're making an extension to emulate our webapp), but when in the extension, `room:update` is never triggered.

**EDIT 2**:

We did a `console.log` on the `socket` object (generated on connect) in `socket.js`. Inside the headers, it appears the host is `dev.mydomain.com`, while the referrer is `www.othersite.com`. Could this be the problem? What does "host" refer to? Host of the socket server, or host of the socket listener? In the latter case, it would make sense it's not reaching `www.othersite.com` over which we have the extension running.

**EDIT 3**: ...And it started working out of nowhere. Must be a race condition somewhere. Closing the question as no longer relevant.

Comment: Can you post any code detailing this problem? It could be something incorrect on the client-side

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It suddenly works. Probably a race condition.